# How to obtain other user's profile using AWS iOS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-ios

I am using AWS Amplify for iOS and I can get current logged in user's attributes such as names, email, etc. However, I also need to display name/profile picture of other users as well (in places such as posts, comments from the other user). I am not seeing any Amplify or AWSMobileClient API to obtain that information. Can anyone please point me to any such capability?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not possible and may be for a good reason. Instead, I created a web service and used AdminGetUser API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html with appropriate IAM credentials.